# Unity2D Raycasting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a script that will reload the level when the player gets hit by an enemy. I am new to gamedev and c# so I am not 100% confident with my code.

I am getting a few errors that are throwing me off and I can't find anything online that points me in the right direction.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RobotAttack : MonoBehaviour 
{

void Update()
{

    RaycastHit2D hit;
    Vector2 attackPosition = transform.position + new Vector2(0f, 1f);

    if (Physics2D.Raycast(attackPosition, transform.forward, hit, 1f) && (hit.transform.tag == "Player"))        
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }       
}
}
```

The errors I am getting are as follows.

```
Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(14,44): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2)' and `UnityEngine.Vector3.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'

Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,66): error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `hit'

Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,23): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Physics2D.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector2, UnityEngine.Vector2, float, int)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,23): error CS1503: Argument `#3' cannot convert `UnityEngine.RaycastHit2D' expression to type `float'
```

Apologies if this is formatted horribly, this is my first post in this site :^)
Thanks.

Comment: Formatted exceptionally well! Thanks for making the effort!

Answer (score 0):

> Assets/Scripts/Robotack.cs(14,44): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous
>   between the following methods or properties:
>   `UnityEngine.Vector2.operator +(UnityEngine.Vector2,
>   UnityEngine.Vector2)' and`UnityEngine.Vector3.operator
>   +(UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Vector3)'

This means there is another method with the same name and so the compiler does not know which one you intend to use. Namely: `Vector2.operator` and `Vector3.operator` changing the name will resolve this or specifying the prefixing library.

> Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,66): error CS0165: Use of unassigned
>   local variable `hit'

This is quite clear cut, you have not defined `hit` to be anything, only its type. 
You could try : 
`RaycastHit2D hit = new RaycastHit2D();`

But I am not sure of its contructor.

**Edit: *After reviewing constructor:***

[Raycast Documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html)

> Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,23): error CS1502: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.Physics2D.Raycast(UnityEngine.Vector2,
>   UnityEngine.Vector2, float, int)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Assets/Scripts/RobotAttack.cs(17,23): error CS1503: Argument `#3'
>   cannot convert`UnityEngine.RaycastHit2D' expression to type `float'

This simply means the parameter you are trying to pass in is of the wrong type. Notable, the third parameter is not a `float` infact it looks like you are passing in a `RaycastHit2D` type object. You could try to cast this to a float if you are confident it will cast, although it's highly unlikely. Alternatively you will need to establish the correct input variable to use.

Hope this helps a little!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me! Regarding the first error, the only method where I am using Vector2 is

    Vector2 attackPosition = transform.position + new Vector2(0f, 1f);

So I am not sure what to rename, if that makes sense :)

Comment: @Ety try using `UnityEngine.Vector2 attackPosition = transform.position + new UnityEngine.Vector2(0f, 1f);` to specify which library you are referring to .